# How to listen for highlighted text in a custom macro in TexShop with AppleScript?

Tags: macros, texshop

I would like to create a custom macro in TexShop with AppleScript (or any other tool) which you activate like a mode which listens for any text highlighting in the file. If the mode is activated, every time you highlight some text, a procedure is triggered which uses that text in some way. The mode stays on until you turn it off. Would this be possible, or what would the nearest solution for this be? Are there any Latex editors which use a scripting language that has listening capabilities, or could it at least be achieved from the command line?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is "Services" on MacOS. You setup a custom menu item in "Servies", select the text, right click and invoke the desired "Services" option which is passed the highlighted text and can also replace the highlighted text with something else or perform what ever script you desire.

Comment: As an example type "~/Dropbox" (or some directory that you know exists) in TeXShop (or any text editor), highlight this text, right click and select "Services/Show in Finder" and this opens a Finder Window to the given directory.  You can create your own Servies menu items, but not sure that is on topic for this site.  Perhaps [Ask Dfferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com) might be a more appropriate place to ask on how to setup services to do this.

Comment: First, if it is to get triggered by selecting text alone how can it `know' when you are done highlighting that text? There are many ways to select text. I think it would have to be something you trigger (possibly with a keyboard shortcut).